# Sql server Convert Datetime to UTC

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am saving date as Indian standard format in SQL server. SQL Server is in Oman server with 1.30 hours back than Indian time.

date -> '2018-04-04 4:00'

I need to convert this date to 
'2018-04-04 2:30' using query. How to do this in SQL server. How to handle this dynamically for different server with different time zone

Comment: Best is to store as UTC always, convert to UTC when storing, convert back to local when retrieving/displaying. Same reason why MS SQL Azure enforces this for all regions worldwide.

Comment: I agree you should store as UTC always. But assuming your workstation is in Indian standard time, try something like: `DECLARE @date datetime = '2018-04-04 4:00'; SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), @date);`

Comment: It gets '2018-04-04 00:00:00.000'. Is it possible to get '2018-04-04 2:30'